# Table view in Xamarin.Form

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I have been trying to use the Table View in Xamarin.Form. Is it possible to make something like this with the table view[Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L5jl9.jpg)

Comment: Please [ask] before posting.  Instead of asking a yes or no question, it would be better if you posted the code you have tried and explained what specific problem you are having with it.

Answer (score 0):

Xamarin.Form provides the contrl `TableView` to achieve. If you set his Intent as Settings, you can display a nice list of configuration settings like SwitchCell, EntryCell, or a CustomCell.

A simple code for your reference:

```
<TableView Intent="Settings">
        <TableRoot>
            <TableSection>
                <ViewCell>
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Label Text="Settings" FontSize="Large"></Label>
                        <SearchBar></SearchBar>
                    </StackLayout>
                </ViewCell>
                <ImageCell ImageSource="icon.png" Text="Johan Smith"></ImageCell>
            </TableSection>
            <TableSection Title="Language Settings">
                <TextCell Text="Song Language"   />
                <TextCell Text="Display Language"   />
            </TableSection>
            <TableSection Title="Play Settings">                   
                <TextCell Text="Equalizer" />
                <SwitchCell Text="Night Mode" />
                <SwitchCell Text="Sleep Timer" />
            </TableSection>                
        </TableRoot>
    </TableView>
```

Refer to the Docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/tableview

You could download the code sample from the link below. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/userinterface-tableview/